# What is the difference between an Internet of Things (IoT) environment and other environments?

Tags: web, cloud, distributed, iot, distributed-system

What makes IoT environment different from other environments (e.g., cloud, pervasive, web)? In general, the latter are components of the IoT environment, but what are the specific properties of IoT?

Comment: does my answer help ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I feel that few things are left out. I'm looking to see if someone else came across this question, and can contribute with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it all wrong.

IoT is a network of physical things whereas Cloud is an on-demand resource provider (mainly computation and storage).

IoT is a more of a problem or solution identification. Cloud is a platform where you do your computation.